# How do I setup a static route through a Windows Server I only have RDP access to?

Tags: networking, vpn

This is bit of a strange question, but I'm trying to figure out a nice solution:

1. I have VPN access to my work network and get RDP access (or VNC access to Linux boxes). My gateway IP address is actually different from these boxes.
2. I need to access a box on a remote network that doesn't have my VPN IP address, but my work's external IP address. So I cannot setup a static route using my VPN IP address.
3. Since I can RDP into a box into a network that has an IP address with a gateway address that let's me get to the remote network, is there anyway I can set it up so that I can use that box to tunnel or act as a gateway IP address so I can access the remote network?

Use case: I have SVN access to a client network that has our work's gateway address, because our VPN is hosted externally the gateway address is different and I'm told we cannot do static routes on our VPN (I usually do a route add in Windows to accomplish). However, away from the office I *can* VPN, RDP into a box on the work network and access what I need. There's gotta be away I can say, hey, route all my traffic for this certain IP address through the dev box, is this possible?

Comment: If you could SSH through the virtual tunnel (VPN) to a dev box then you could certainly route traffic through it using `tsocks`. But bouncing traffic via RDP is highly unlikely as RDP is not tunneling traffic but merely drawing and user-input instructions.

Comment: Sweet! I can setup SSH on the box, by "RDP access" I meant that I can access the box and accomplish what I need so I felt there was a solution. So if I use tsocks, then I could so an SVN commit and it'll route the SVN traffic through the dev box?

Comment: You can create a "SOCKS proxy" using the -D flag (or similar in Putty) when you ssh, e.g. `ssh -D9999 me@dev.myoffice.com`. Then if you install `tsocks` on your home Linux computer and edit `/etc/tsocks.conf` and set `server_port=9999` and `server=127.0.0.1` then you can run `tsocks svn status` and it will go via your dev box.